# Jest test passes even though the expect toHaveStyle wasn't correct

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, snapshot

I am attempting to test the following code using jest.

```
 if (config?.rgba1 && config?.rgba2 && config?.backgroundImageURL)
    backgroundImageConfig = `linear-gradient(${config.rgba1}, ${config.rgba2}), url(${config.backgroundImageURL})`;
  else if (config?.rgba1 && config?.rgba2)
    backgroundImageConfig = `linear-gradient(${config.rgba1}, ${config.rgba2})`;
  else if (config?.backgroundImageURL)
    backgroundImageConfig = `url(${config.backgroundImageURL})`;

  return (
    <section
      id={anchorID}
      style={{
        background: config?.backgroundColor ? config?.backgroundColor : "#eee",
        backgroundImage: backgroundImageConfig,
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        padding: "1rem",
      }}
    >
```

I have written this test and expected the  to have a gradient background based on the else if in the code. The test is passing, but the result is not what I expected when I look at the snapshot.

```
    const viewData = {
      type: "pageView",
      feature: "page1",
      alt: "Page img",
      title: "Gradient colors",
      config: {
        titleColor: "black",
        rgba1: "midnightblue",
        rgba2: "lightblue",
        backgroundColor: "",
        backgroundImageURL: "",
        backgroundImageOpacity: "",
        showImage: "",
        showButton: "",
      },
    };
    const { container } = render(
      <PageView
        viewData={viewData}
        manifestData={manifestData}
      />
    );

    expect(container).toHaveStyle(
      "background: linear-gradient(midnightblue, lightblue)"
    );
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Here is a snip of the snapshot.

```
exports[`PageView Testing will have a gradient background 1`] = `
<div>
  <section
    style="background: rgb(238, 238, 238); background-size: cover; padding: 1rem;"
  >
    <h2
      class="sc-bczRLJ dLraJy"
    >
      Gradient colors
    </h2>
    <div
      style="margin: auto; max-width: 900px;"
    >
```

My initial thought is that I am testing the entire render (container) toHaveStyle and I need to be finding  and testing the toHaveStyle on that item and not the entire container.

I think I may need to do this instead but I am not sure which query to use to access

```
const section = screen.getBy???("")
expect (section).toHaveStyle( "background: linear-gradient(midnightblue, lightblue)")
```

Does the  need to have a id, name, placeholder or something added to it so I can query it in the test?

Comment: It's a bug  :( https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/461. You could probably instead do something with `expect` and `window.getComputedStyle(container).background` though I suspect this way has edge cases that the `toHaveStyle` from the lib was supposed to handle if it was working.